# Print Pretty JSON with React with Interactive Keys

Tags: reactjs, json

I want to pretty print JSON with React, and every key to be a button that displays the value associated when clicked.

I used the following code with the library [react-string-replace](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace) to pretty print the JSON and transform the keys in buttons, but this way I can't get back the value of nested properties (ex: res.foo[0].bar).

```js
reactStringReplace(
   JSON.stringify(jsonData, undefined, 4),
   /"([^"]+)":/g,
   (match, i) => {
      return (
         <button
            key={i}
            className="text-blue-500 hover:underline"
            onClick={handleClick}
         >
            {match}       
         </button>
                  
      );
   }
)
```

Comment: Does something like https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/tree/main/packages/react-json-tree fit your needs? " every key to be a button that displays the value associated when clicked." how would this work UX wise? Do you want a tree?